# Method of least squares in combination with Exponential smoothing

Tags: measure-theory

I have been given a [formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u441Y.png) to compute the squared error of smoothed sequences with the help of the "method of least squares".

There is a sigma $(S_i-X_i)^2$. I have been told that sigma means sum. Does this mean that i need to sum the squared value of (the difference between the smoothed sequence minus demand) of each available row and then take the root?

Example:

Demand --- Smoothed sequence
$165$ --- $163$
$171$ --- $164$

Squared error

$\sqrt{(((163-165)^2 + (164-171)^2)/2)}$

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Yes, but In your example, inside the square root, you need to divide by n - 1 = 1, not by n = 2.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Thank you for your answer. Just to be sure, given the formula, the correct version should be $\sqrt{(((163-165)^2 + (164-171)^2)/1)}$ and the answer of this question should be $7,28011$ then?

Comment: Yes. ..........